# Issue when deleting the items from the array in document of MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am inserting log items in the document in the form of an array. I have restricted document size up to 5MB to make sure that the document size is not increased.

Here one document contains one array and all the log items will be stored into the array. Lets say I have `500 log items of 5 MB` size is stored in one document in the form an array.

When I delete 497 log items,It is showing the remaining 3 log items in the document but when I tried to delete one of the items from the 3 log items, the entire document was deleted, I don't know What is happening.

Is the array in the document should have some minimum number size of data.

Note: I am restricting the document size at my application level.

Here is the sample data:

```
activityLogDetails:
  [{
  "activityLog": {
    "acctId": 1,
    "info1": {
      "itemName": "-",
      "value": "-"
    },
    "info2": {
      "itemName": "-",
      "value": "-"
    },
    "errorCode": "",
    "internalInformation": "",
    "kind": "Infomation",
    "loginId": "0",
    "opeLogId": "G1_1",
    "operation": "startDiscovery",
    "result": "normal",
    "targetId": "1",
    "timestamp": "1470980265729",
    "undoFlag": "false"
  }
},{
  "activityLog": {
    "acctId": 2,
    "info1": {
      "itemName": "-",
      "value": "-"
    },
    "info2": {
      "itemName": "-",
      "value": "-"
    },
    "errorCode": "",
    "internalInformation": "",
    "kind": "Infomation",
    "loginId": "0",
    "opeLogId": "G1_1",
    "operation": "startDiscovery",
    "result": "normal",
    "targetId": "1",
    "timestamp": "1470980265729",
    "undoFlag": "false"
  }
}, 
etc....]
```

Delete Query:

```
db.test.remove({activityLogDetails.activityLog.acctId:{$gt:2}})
```

Could any body tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: could you add code how you delete data?

Comment: I am deleting the data from MongoBooster, Please look into my updated question

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your query, will remove the whole record.

Try the following query using `$pull`:-

```
db.test.updateMany(
        {'activityLogDetails.activityLog.acctId':{$gt:2}},
        {$pull:{activityLogDetails:{'activityLog.acctId':{$gt:2}}}})
```

Refer [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) for more info on how to use.

Comment: Hello @profesor, Thank you for reminding me!!. Can I store each activityLog as an item in the document without using array

Comment: Query is not working @profesor, Can you please look into it once again

Comment: @M.S.Naidu you need to ask OP for that :-)